# What is the difference between deployment and installation in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: integrate-remedy-sp2013

I am trying to understand "add-in web( app web)" & "host web". I found the following point about them:

"The special website to which the add-in is  deployed is called an add-in web. The website to which the add-in is  installed is called thehost web."

Now, to undertand it better, I want to know that what is the difference between 'deployment' and 'installation' in SharePoint 2013?

Comment: For more information about AppWeb & HostWeb, pls refer:https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/142425/host-web-apps-vs-app-web-apps

Answer (score 2):

Usually in sharepoint the deployment just copy the files to hives and gac directories,

the installation makes deployed content available to use.
not sure if this answer your question about the add-ins tho.

Answer (score 1):

The very short and exact to the point to your question, the answer is,

> Publishing to the Office Store(For SharePoint Online) or an organization's add-in catalog(For SharePoint On-Premises) is
>   called as deployment of App.

and

> Adding that Add-in to your SharePoint site using **Site Content -> Add
>   an App** is called as Installation of Add-in

Let me know if you want to go more deep into it.

For more short description you can refer [Deploying and installing SharePoint Add-ins](https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/sp-add-ins/deploying-and-installing-sharepoint-add-ins-methods-and-options)